# I have problem with install webpack react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, eslint

> this is error

```
'React' is defined but never used
```

> this is file app.js

```
import React from 'react';
```

> this file webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "main.js",
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_module/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|j?g|svg|gif)?$/,
        use: "file-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/index.html"),
      filename: "index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

> this is link that i learned
>   https://medium.com/@imranhsayed/set-up-react-app-with-webpack-webpack-dev-server-and-babel-from-scratch-df398174446d
>
> i have problem in step7 , i istalled npm install eslint-plugin-react --save-dev but can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, is this the entirety of your app.js file?

`import React from 'react';`

Or have you also written the rest of the app.js file as laid out in step 7 of your link?

The error message you're seeing indicates that you have imported a module (React) but that you have yet to use it for anything. If `import React from 'react';` is the entire contents of your app.js file, then this is to be expected; as you finish writing the app.js file, this error message will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You took a road that requires quite a lot of manualy work. For a beginner and even experienced users I strongly recommend the well known CRA tool ([create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)). It takes care to set up everything for you, including Babel and Webpack. Of course this depends on the actual React project, but I found that an excellent start.